# Find $f(t,w)$ such that $\int_0^{2 \pi} f(t, w) \ln|\delta(t) - \delta(\theta)| dt = \ln|w - \delta(\theta)|$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, fluid-dynamics

### Problem

As part of a 2d Stokes flow fluid simulation I'm working on I'm trying to find a $f(t, w)$ such that

$$\int_0^{2 \pi} f(t, w) \ln|\delta(t) - \delta(\theta)| dt = \ln|w - \delta(\theta)|, \forall \theta \in [0, 2\pi)$$

where $w \in \mathbb{C}, |w| < 1$ and $\delta(t)$ is just a complex finite fourier series: $$\delta(t) = \sum_{n=-N}^N c_n e^{int}, c_n \in \mathbb{C}$$

### Partial solutution

If $\delta(t) = e^{it}$ I have that

$$f(t, w) = \frac{1}{\pi} Re\Big(\frac{1}{1 - w e^{-it}}\Big)$$

to give some flavor of what $f(t,w)$ might look like (this value for $f(t,w)$ is not unique).  I'm trying to generalize this result to a wider class of $\delta(t)$, ideally all finite Fourier series but maybe it's only possible for a certain class, I'm not sure.

### Possible approach?

I thought maybe I could factor $\delta(t) - \delta(\theta)$ as $a e^{-iNt} \prod_{n=-N}^N (e^{it} - \alpha_n)$.  Then the log term is linearly seperable:

$$ \ln|a e^{iNt} \prod_{n=-N}^N (e^{it} - \alpha_n) | = \ln|a| + \sum_{n=-N}^N \ln|e^{it} - \alpha_n| $$

I can then split the integral into smaller, solvable pieces:

$$\int_0^{2 \pi} f(t, w) \ln|\delta(t) - \delta(\theta)| dt = $$
$$\ln|a| \int_0^{2 \pi} f(t, w) dt + \sum_{n=-N}^N \int_0^{2 \pi} f(t, w) \ln|e^{it} - \alpha_n| dt$$

Assuming $|\alpha_n| = 1$, (which is a big assumption!), I think I can use my solution for $\delta(t) = e^{it}$ and a little bit of linear algebra to build up a more complex solution.  But the $\theta$ term disappears in the factorization (I have to pick some arbitrary value of $\theta$ to even do the factorization).  Maybe that's okay?  My solution when $\delta(t) = e^{it}$ should hold for all $\theta$ so maybe picking a value for $\theta$ arbitrarily is okay?  It's unclear to me and I'm not sure how to justify or refute the idea.

Any help would be appreciated.  Mostly I'm out of tools in my toolbox and I'm not sure if I'm on the right track or if this is even possible in principle.

Comment: Do you know whether $\delta$ is invertible?

Comment: @md2perpe that's an interesting question!  In general a Fourier series isn't invertible, but the class of $\delta$ I'm interested correspond to closed curves in the complex plane, and requiring that they are simple (I think that would mean invertible except at the start/end of the curve where it meets?) seems like a reasonable concession.

Comment: Would it be okay with $f$ being a Dirac $\delta$-like distribution? Or must $f$ be a function?

Comment: @md2perpe a function is preferable.  $f$ corresponds to a physical force on the surface of a curve embedded in a fluid.  A point-like force (or superposition of such forces) would likely create singularities somewhere, which I'm purposefully trying to avoid.  But a solution in terms of point-like forces could still be interesting and might point in a fruitful direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve this for a slightly larger class of curves.  The result is interesting so I thought I'd share:

First, generalize $\delta(t) - \delta(\theta)$ to the interior of the unit disk and call it $\gamma(z)$:

$$\gamma(z) = \left( \sum_{n=-N}^N c_n z^n \right) - \delta(\theta), c_n \in \mathbb{C}.$$

Basically, $\gamma(e^{it}) = \delta(t) - \delta(\theta)$.  Crucially, *assume that $\gamma(z)$ has no roots in the unit disk*.  Note that $\gamma(z)$ is analytic and $\ln|\gamma(z)|$ is harmonic.

Find a value $y$ such that $\gamma(y) = w - \delta(\theta)$ and $|y| < 1$, *assuming there is one* (it helps here to relax the requirements on $w$ from the original question and instead place those requirements on $y$).

Then we can construct a Poisson Integral:

$$ \log|w - \delta(\theta)| = \log|\gamma(y)| = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{2\pi} P_r(\phi - t) \log|\gamma(e^{it})|dt, \ \ \ \ y = r e^{i \phi}$$

where $P_r(\theta)$ is the [Poisson Kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel) and is given by

$$ P_r(\phi) = \Re\left( \frac{1 + r e^{i \phi}}{1 - r e^{i \phi}} \right), \ \ \ \ 0 \leq r < 1.$$

Therefore

$$ \boxed{f(t, w) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \Re\left( \frac{1 + y e^{-it}}{1 - y e^{-it}} \right)}$$

Obviously there are a lot of limitations here.  $\gamma(z)$ can't have any roots in the unit disk for *any* value of $\theta$ (if there are roots the Poisson Integral gets some extra terms that I don't know how to account for).  Also you need to be able to find a $y$ in the unit circle, because the Poisson Kernel is only available there.  Otherwise you're free to select $w$ and $\delta(t)$, though.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unfortunate that you have named your function $\delta$ since I'm going to talk about the Dirac delta distribution, normally also denoted by $\delta$. But I will use $u$ for the Dirac delta distribution so that you can keep your notation.

The relation looks quite similar to the definition of a translated Dirac delta distribution $u$:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \, u(x-a) \, dx = f(a).
$$

So if we allow $f$ to be a distribution we would expect
$$
f(t,w) = u(\delta(t)-w)
$$
to work.

Comment: This seems like a promising approach but noticeably $\ln|x| \neq u(x)$. This is not math I'm versed in, but I think the similarity here is that both the $\ln|x|$ and $u(x)$ integrals are essentially convolutions of $f$ by these functions/distributions.  The integral identity you have is apparently called the "sifting property" of the dirac delta function.  If something equivalent existed generally for convolutions or specifically for $\ln|x|$ that would probably get me to an answer.  A bit of googling has not turned up anything obvious yet, though.

Comment: @JayLemmon. It seems like the notations have confused you. I obviously should have changed my $f$ also. And I did use $f$ in two different meanings. My first use was in a general meaning, and my second use was as your $f$. I thus meant
$$
\int_0^{2 \pi} u(\delta(t)-w) \ln|\delta(t) - \delta(\theta)| dt = \ln|w - \delta(\theta)|
$$

Comment: Ah, I see.  Yes, you should probably be more precise with your notation :)  Assuming this works, it's only for a vary narrow case: $w$ has to be on the curve formed by $\delta(t)$.  If not,  then $u(\delta(t) - w)$ will always be 0.  I say assuming, because don't you have to tread carefully here substituting $x=\delta(t)$ as the variable of integration? ie: don't you have to do the substitution $dt = \frac{dx}{\delta'(\delta^{-1}(x))}$?